# How can I make my laptop use a phone as a wi-fi adapter?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, laptop

I have an HP Pavilion dv6400 series laptop with an NVidea chipset which is the subject of a [class action lawsuit](http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/). The symptom ([PDF](http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/pdfs/IdentifiedSymptomsList.pdf)) that I'm experiencing is that the system fails to recognize that there is a wireless adapter installed. It doesn't appear in Device Manager. [In this question](https://superuser.com/questions/199443/hp-laptop-wont-recognize-wireless-adapter), I ask if there's a way to work around this problem.

As an alternative, I'd like to see if there's a way to use an old Windows Mobile 5 phone that does not have cellular service (voice or data) as a Wi-Fi adapter. How can this be accomplished?

The system is running Windows Vista Home and has the latest BIOS (F42) and Windows updates and drivers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "tether" to that older phone. Your best bet is a [usb wifi dongle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_three_br_5?rh=k:usb+wireless+adapter,n:172282,n:!493964,n:541966,n:172504,n:490499011,n:13983791,p_n_feature_two_browse-bin:490503011,p_n_feature_three_browse-bin:405582011|405581011&bbn=13983791&sort=price&keywords=usb+wireless+adapter&ie=UTF8&qid=1287069730&rnid=405575011) - you can find them for < $10.

Comment: I could tether it with cellular data when that phone was in active use. I don't understand why it shouldn't be possible to do it with Wi-Fi.

Comment: Sure, it's possible from a technical standpoint, but if the firmware and software on the phone aren't written to ALLOW it...

Comment: @Dennis: The phone must be able to share the wifi connection, and that's a question of software, like Shinrai points out. It can be easily enabled if the phone vendor releases an updated firmware, otherwise not. (For iOS, but explains my point: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/software-mobile/ios-4-3-adds-wi-fi-hotspot-capability-boosts-safari-performance/).